# React - checkbox input not updating correctly (due to shallow merge)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I believe there are some errors in my code due to shallow merge, particularly my checkbox as it's behaving weirdly. Can someone suggest some inputs on how to fix it?

This is how I'm setting my state and how I handle input change:

```
state = {
  form: {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    rememberMe: false
  }
};

  handleChange = e => {
    const { name, value, checked } = e.target;
    const isCheckbox = checked === "checkbox";
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      form: {
        // all other key value pairs of form object
        ...prevState.form,

        // update this one specifically
        [name]: isCheckbox ? checked : value
      }
    }));
  };
```

Submit and validation

```
  validateForm = () => {
    const formInputs = ["firstName", "lastName", "email", "password", "rememberMe"];

    for (let i = 0; i < formInputs.length; i++) {
      const inputName = formInputs[i];

      if (!this.state.form[inputName].length) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  };

  handleSubmit = () => {
    if (this.validateForm()) {
      console.log("Success!");
      console.log(this.state);
    } else {
      console.log("Failure!");
    }
  };
```

Here's the snippet of my form:

```
   <form
      className="Form"
      onSubmit={e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.handleSubmit();
      }}
    >
      <input name="firstName" onChange={this.handleChange} />
      <input name="lastName" onChange={this.handleChange} />
      <input name="email" onChange={this.handleChange} />
      <input name="password" onChange={this.handleChange} />
      <input
        name="rememberMe"
        type="checkbox"
        checked={this.state.form.rememberMe}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
      <button className="no-padding">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Managed to get 'Success' after submission but my checkbox is behaving weirdly and stays on checked.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it should be

```
 const { name, value, checked, type } = e.target;
 const isCheckbox = type === "checkbox";
```

Or

```
 const { name, value, checked } = e.target;
     const isCheckbox = name === "rememberMe";
```

Comment: I changed the code to the above and it gave me a 'Failure' after I submitted

Comment: What is the error? Stack trace? You can also use name to check if it is checkbox

Comment: There's no error on the application but the form failed to submit (I got console log "Failure")

Comment: it could be that there's no validation for the checkbox and that's it rendered as 'Failure'? what's the best approach to tackle checkbox validation?

Comment: If it is not a mandatory field you can exclude that field from validation